# ASP MVC 3 On build server missing WebApplication.targets

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, msbuild, nant

I have an ASP.MVC 3 project that I am trying to get building on our build server.  We are using nant for our build script to do a variety of stuff, however we are using the MSBUILD task to compile our code.  Our MVC3 project won't compile on the build machine with the error that it is missing `cMicrosoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`.

I have installed the Windows .NET SDK and included Tools and Reference Assemblies and I've installed MVC 3 on the server.

Copying "WebApplication.targets" to my solution directory is not an option.
Installing Visual Studio on the build machine is not an option.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not unique for ASP.NET MVC. The same issue exists with the old ASP.NET web application projects. The common solution has been to copy the stated folder from a computer that has Visual Studio installed to your build machine.

Comment: Wow, I actually don't remember ever having this problem with old ASP.NET apps.  This is a new build machine though, so maybe we did do that on our old ones and I just don't remember.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I had this issue when setting up a new build machine for my VS 2008 ASP.NET web application projects at work.